# Action:support not working with wrapper class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a vf page where i am using action:support with wrapper class. But when the action:support is fired i am not getting any values.

**Apex Class**

```
public with sharing class RFPController{

    public RFP__c accounts;
        public Custom_Package__c del;
        public List < Custom_Package__c > addattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delattendeeList {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > attendeeList {get;set;}
        public Integer totalCount {get;set;}

        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}
        public Integer deleterowIndex {get;set;}
        public List < Custom_Package__c > delAttendees {get;set;}
        public Boolean isRerender{get;set;}
        //public String S {get;set;}
         public Integer numberOfRowToRemove { get; set; }
         public String selectedRowIndex{get;set;} 
        //public Integer count = 1;
         public Integer c{get; set;} 
         //public Integer counter{get;set;}
         private List<SelectOption> options;
         public List<SelectOption> AllName{get;set;}
         public List<SelectOption> AllDept{get;set;}
        // public String discountScheduleID { get; set; }
        public  string mark {get; set;}


        private List<Custom_Package__c>  acc {get;set;}

        public RFPController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

                isRerender = false;
                accounts =  (RFP__c )controller.getRecord();
                String S = 'Select id, Name, Market__c, State__c, First_Issue__c,Last_Issue__c,Circulation__c,Space_Unit__c,Per_Unit_Open_Rate__c,Space_Discount__c from Custom_Package__c ';
                //totalCount = attendeeList.size();
                attendeeList  = Database.Query(S);
                attendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c >();

                delattendeeList = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();
                delattendees = new List < Custom_Package__c > ();

                accounts.Rep_Name__c= Userinfo.getuserId();
                c=0;
               AllName = getMarket();
                Alldept = getDept();
                attendeeList1 = new List<CustomPackageWrapper>();
                for(integer i=0;i<1;i++){

                CustomPackageWrapper cw1 = new CustomPackageWrapper(new Custom_Package__c());
                attendeeList1.add(cw1);
                }
        }

        public void addRow() {
                isRerender = true;

               CustomPackageWrapper cw = new CustomPackageWrapper(new Custom_Package__c());

               attendeeList1.add(cw);


        }



    public List<ID> discountScheduleID {
        get {
            if (discountScheduleID == null) {
                discountScheduleID = new List<ID>();
            }
            return discountScheduleID ;
        }
        set;
    }

      public List<SelectOption> getDept()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        //options.add(new SelectOption('Select','--Select--'));

        for(Custom_Package__c Proj  :[select Id, Name from Custom_Package__c ] )
             {
                    system.debug('3333333'); 
                    options.add(new SelectOption(Proj.ID,Proj.Name));

             }
        return options;

    }


   public Integer selectedRowIdx {get; set;}
   Public List<CustomPackageWrapper> cplist = new List<CustomPackageWrapper>();
   public CustomPackageWrapper cp = new CustomPackageWrapper (new Custom_Package__c() ); 


    public List<SelectOption> getMarket(){
        system.debug('^^^^^^^^ Entered' +cp.discountSchedule );
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            //cp.discountSchedule = new List<ID>();

         for(Custom_Package__c Proj1  :[select Id,Name,Market__c from Custom_Package__c where ID IN:cp.discountSchedule] )
                {                    
                    system.debug('3333333' + cp.discountSchedule ); 

                    options.add(new SelectOption(Proj1.ID,Proj1.Market__c ));

                }

        system.debug('^^^^^^^^ Entered' + options.size());        
        return options;


    }

    public string selectedMarketIds {get; set;}  

        public void FindAllName()
    {
        AllName= new List<SelectOption>();
        AllDept= new List<SelectOption>();
        system.debug('!!!!!!! Entered');
        AllName = getMarket();
        Alldept = getDept();
        system.debug('&&&&&&& Entered' + AllName );

    }

    public List<CustomPackageWrapper> attendeeList1 {
        get {if (attendeeList1 == null)
             attendeeList1 = new List<CustomPackageWrapper>();
             return attendeeList1;
       }
        set;
        }



        public class CustomPackageWrapper {
        public Custom_Package__c cp {get; set;}
        //public List<ID> discountSchedule {get; set;}
        //public String discountSchedule1 {get; set;}
        public Integer rowIndex {get;set;}

        public List<ID> discountSchedule {
        get {
            if (discountSchedule == null) {
                discountSchedule = new List<ID>();
            }
            return discountSchedule ;
        }
        set;
        }

        public List<String> discountSchedule1 {get;set;}

        public CustomPackageWrapper(Custom_Package__c cp) {


        this.cp = cp;


        }


        }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable"  var="acc" value="{!attendeeList1}" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">

             <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
            <apex:commandLink value="Copy" reRender="pb" onclick="testMe(event)"/>
          </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package">
                 <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
                         <apex:selectList multiselect="true" value="{!acc.discountSchedule}"  styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" size="1" style="width:400px;" >
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}" rerender="geographies"  oncomplete="renderChosen()"/>
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Dept}"/>
                      </apex:selectList> 
                <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/> 
          </apex:column>


          <apex:column headerValue="Market" id="market">
            <apex:outputPanel id="geographies" layout="block" >
          <apex:selectList id="selectedmarkets" multiselect="false" value="{!acc.discountSchedule1}"  styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" size="1" style="width:150px" >

              <apex:selectOptions value="{!Market}"/>
             </apex:selectList> 
            </apex:outputPanel>
          </apex:column>
```

Comment: Any thoughts????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't figure out why a specific feature isn't working in a largish piece of code, create a small test page and controller focussed on that feature and debug and figure out the problem there. Then apply that working pattern back in the largish piece of code.

One confusion in your code is that you are using the variable name `cp` in two places: don't use the same name for different things. In fact I suggest a **re-write** where you remove all the unused variables and name everything carefully (e.g. use plurals for collections) and indent your code accurately and remove the spurious white space. That will make it easier for you to reason about the code.

It looks like one problem is that although there can be many rows with different sets of `discountSchedule` IDs selected you are trying to use a single set of `Market` options. Instead add another field and method to your wrapper:

```
public class CustomPackageWrapper {
    public List<Id> discountSchedule {...}
    public List<SelectOption> marketOptions {...}
    ...
    public void updateMarketOptions() {
        marketOptions.clear();
        for (Custom_Package__c> cp : [
                select Id, Market__c
                from Custom_Package__c
                where Id in :discountSchedule
                order by Market__c
                ]) {
            marketOptions.add(new SelectOption(cp.Id, cp.Market__c));
        }
    }
}
```

Then instead of:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!FindAllName}"
        rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()"/>
...
<apex:selectOptions value="{!Market}"/>
```

update and display the options for the row:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!acc.updateMarketOptions}"
        rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()"/>
...
<apex:selectOptions value="{!acc.marketOptions}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Keith, I am getting this following error......
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Error is in expression '{!acc.updateMarketOptions}' in page autopopu: Class.RFPController.CustomPackageWrapper.updateMarketOptions: line 176, column 1

Class.RFPController.CustomPackageWrapper.updateMarketOptions: line 176, column 1

Comment: @Sid I've outlined the changes I think you should make not written every line of code for you.

Comment: @Sid While a "thanks" comment is nice, clicking the up-arrow (or down-arrow) is the better way to acknowledge an answer.